# What's the relation between Sakurai chapter 7.8 and QED?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, hamiltonian

In Sakurai quantum mechanics section 7.8, the book tries to quantize the Maxwell's equations in free space $$\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol{E}=0$$
$$\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol{B}=0$$
$$\nabla\times\boldsymbol{E}+\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{B}}{\partial t}=0$$
$$\nabla\times\boldsymbol{B}-\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{E}}{\partial t}=0$$
by using the Coulomb gauge $\boldsymbol{A}$ then take a Fourier transform of $\boldsymbol{A}$, then let the Hamiltonian be $$H=\sum_{k,\lambda}\hbar\omega_ka_\lambda^\dagger(\boldsymbol{k})a_\lambda(\boldsymbol{k})+E_0.$$

My question is: how is this method related to a proper QED treatment?

Comment: There’s absolutely nothing wrong with this treatment, and it’s common in fields like atomic physics. In high energy physics you would do something more complicated because there we try to keep gauge symmetry and Lorentz invariance manifest.

Comment: Thanks! So can I say Sakurai's treatment is equivalent to QED's, is just Sakurai's is not manifestly Lorentz invariant?

Comment: The main substantive difference with real QED is that QED includes degrees of freedom for the electron/positron, and importantly the *interaction* between the electron and the electromagnetic field. However, the first step in a "real" QED treatment is to quantize the free fields, ignoring the interactions, which is what Sakurai is doing.